# overlay css play button

Tags: html, css

I need to add an image to overlay a play button only when you hover over an image, I have it somewhat working, however I can't get it over the image, it only shows up behind the image. I've tried setting the Z-index to be higher but it still wont' work.

Here is my markup for the HTML

```
<div class="articles"><img alt="image1" src="Resources/092812newshubgmtseg1b_167x94.jpg">
            <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Beatus sibi videtur. 3:40</figcaption>
        </div>
```

and here is my CSS

```
.articles img {
    width: 143px;
    height: 85px;
    z-index: 1;
}



.articles img:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px #2ecc71 solid;
    border-top: 5px #2ecc71 solid;
    z-index: 1;
}

.articles:hover{
    color:#2ecc71;
    background: url(Resources/play.png);
    z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: z-index only works when position is applied

Comment: applied to the hover state?

Comment: wherever you use z-index as a style, you need the position style to accompany it

Comment: tried adding position still no luck.

Comment: Position doesn't magically make it work, I can help if you set up a live example with the code

Answer (score 3):

First: parent elements will never get "on top" of their child elements. So setting `.article` to a higher `z-index` than its child `.article img` will never work.

You could use the `:after` pseudo selector to dynamically add some extra content to the `.article` element on `:hover`. Here's an example:

```css
.articles img {
  width: 143px;
  height: 85px;
}

.articles img:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px #2ecc71 solid;
  border-top: 5px #2ecc71 solid;
}

.articles:hover:after{
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 70px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  color: #2ecc71;
  background: url("http://dummyimage.com/40x20/666666/fff&text=PLAY");
}
```

```html
<div class="articles">
  <img alt="image1" src="http://dummyimage.com/143x85/666/fff">
  <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Beatus sibi videtur. 3:40</figcaption>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this solution [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksen/ctxde507/), hope it will help you

```css
.articles img {width:143px;height:85px;z-index:1;}
.articles img:hover {border-bottom: 5px #2ecc71 solid;border-top: 5px #2ecc71 solid;z-index: 1;}
.top {Position:absolute;z-index:999;top:5px;opacity:0;}
.top:hover{opacity:1;}
.behind {position:relative;z-index:10;}
```

```html
<div class="articles"><div class="behind"><img  alt="image1" src="http://media.marketwatch.com/video/20120928/092812newshubgmtseg1b/092812newshubgmtseg1b_1280x720.jpg"></div><div class="top"><img style="z-index:1;position:absolute;" alt="image1" src="http://wyeoakmusic.com/site/wp-content/plugins/haiku-minimalist-audio-player/resources/play.png"></div>
            <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Beatus sibi videtur. 3:40</figcaption>
        </div>
```